# How to convert sql count with where condition in python/pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the below sql query,

```
count(ticket_id) from interactions  as intr
where ticket_status='PENDING'
```

I need to acheive the same in python. I tried the below approach. Is anything could be better than this?

```
subset_df = df[df["ticket_status"]== 'PENDING']
column_count = subset_df.count()
```

This will give me the count of status column only.
But I'm trying to get the ticket id with that where condition.

I want to count the ticket id with that particular status. Any help would be appreciatable.

Answer (score 1):

What works for me is: `df[df["ticket_status"]== 'PENDING'].value_counts().count()`
This will give the number of tickets that have a ticket_status of 'PENDING'.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to count all distinct instances in a column you can use
`df['ticket_status'].value_counts()`

For counting values with conditional you can use
`df.where(df['ticket_status'] == 'myvalue').count()`

A helpful guide for you to compare your queries from SQL to pandas would be https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/comparison/comparison_with_sql.html

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
df.ticket_status.value_counts()
```